# Complex check-methods with boost.test

Tags: testing, boost

I want to test different constructors of a string class. Therefore I wrote myself a test method that checks a couple standard things:

```
void checkStringStandards(String& s, size_t length, const char* text){
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(s.length(), length);
    ...
}
```

Then I added a test method

```
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(String_construct){
    String s1;
    checkStringStandards(s1, 0, "");

    String s2("normal char");
    checkStringStandards(s2, 11, "normal char");
}
```

The problem is, that when it fails, I only get the line- and file information from within checkStringStandards ! I can't know by the output whether the first or the second call caused this.

What's the common fix for that?

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

The solution to this problem is to write a custom predicate that performs the checks and use `BOOST_REQUIRE(custom_predicate(args))` in the different test cases.  A custom predicate can take any arguments you want and returns [`boost::test_tools::predicate_result`](http://user.xmission.com/~legalize/boost.test/libs/test/doc/html/test/reference/test_classes/predicate_result.html), a type that is compatible with the assertion macros in Boost.Test into which you can build up a detailed diagnostic message during failure.

To use your example:

```
using namespace boost::test_tools;
predicate_result checkStringStandards(String& s, size_t length, const char* text) {
    predicate_result result{true};
    if (s.length() != length) {
        result = false;
        result.message() << "\nString " << s
            << " differs in length; expected: "
            << length << ", actual: " << s.length();
    }
    ...
    return result;
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(String_construct){
    String s1;
    BOOST_REQUIRE(checkStringStandards(s1, 0, ""));

    String s2("normal char");
    BOOST_REQUIRE(checkStringStandards(s2, 11, "normal char"));
}
```

The curious `\n` at the beginning of the message is so that when the diagnostic is printed, the text with "String ... differs in length" will be emitted on it's own line.  If the predicate fails, it bubbles its failure up to `BOOST_REQUIRE` which will trigger the test failure and report the failure at the line invoking `BOOST_REQUIRE` instead of inside your custom predicate.

There is another yuckier alternative that also achieves the same result by making your custom assertions as gigantic megamacros, but I find that so horrid I'm not even going to show an example of how to do it :).

Answer (score 0):

there is no common fix for that. these BOOST_CHECK_... macros exist by intention to avoid function calls where the line number gets lost (unless explicitely passed as param).

you can get round this problem by looping through the parameter set inside your test case.